# Need sample Java code to run a shellscript

Tags: java, shell

I tried with many different examples, but it is not working.

I would really appreciate some sample Java code to run a shell script.

Comment: ???? can you be more explicit?

Comment: A bit more context would be nice, yes.

Answer (score 4):

You need Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...). See [a very extensive example](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4) (don't forget to read the first three pages).

Keep in mind that Runtime.exec is *not a shell*; if you wish to execute a shell script your command line would look like

```
/bin/bash scriptname
```

That is, the shell binary you need is fully qualified (although I suspect that /bin is always in the path). You can not assume that if

```
myshell> foo.sh
```

runs,

```
Runtime.getRuntime.exec("foo.sh");
```

also runs as you are already in a running shell in the first example, but not in the Runtime.exec.

A tested example (Works on My Linux Machine(TM)), mosly cut-and-past from [the previously mentioned article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class ShellScriptExecutor {

    static class StreamGobbler extends Thread {
        InputStream is;

        String type;

        StreamGobbler(InputStream is, String type) {
            this.is = is;
            this.type = type;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String line = null;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                    System.out.println(type + ">" + line);
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("USAGE: java ShellScriptExecutor script");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {
            String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
            String[] cmd = new String[2];
            cmd[0] = "/bin/sh"; // should exist on all POSIX systems
            cmd[1] = args[0];

            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            System.out.println("Execing " + cmd[0] + " " + cmd[1] );
            Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);
            // any error message?
            StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(proc
                    .getErrorStream(), "ERROR");

            // any output?
            StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(proc
                    .getInputStream(), "OUTPUT");

            // kick them off
            errorGobbler.start();
            outputGobbler.start();

            // any error???
            int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
            System.out.println("ExitValue: " + exitVal);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if script is 'chmod +x'd and has first line #!/bin/sh, then it can be executed directly.

Comment: Also in a Runtime.exec() ? I thought it was the shell which checks the first line of the script to see if it starts with a #!. It's always great to learn something new.

Answer (score 3):

Shell Script test.sh code

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "good"
```

Java Code to execute shell script test.sh

```
      try {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process pr = rt.exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "./test.sh"});

            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```