# run jar in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, executable-jar

My problem is that I want to run some jar files in eclipse within a plugin. This jars make analysis on an eclipse project:

```
String run_tool ="cmd.exe /C start java -Xmx400m -cp org-jcolumbus.jar;org-jcolumbus-schema.jar;lib/antlr.jar org.jcolumbus.tool.BuildModel -tasks "+src_dir+" -jsi "+SelProj.getLocation()+"/result/temp/"+SelProj.getName();
Runtime rt2 = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process sp2 = rt2.exec(run_tool);
```

"`src_dir`" is source dir of the eclipse project

`"SelProj.getLocation()+"/result/temp/"+SelProj.getName()"` is a result dir in the selected eclipse project, the results come here.

After the jars' running, I want to rename the "temp" folder to other one, but the eclipse renames the "temp" folder before the jars finish the running, so the jars don't work fairly.

I try to use the `sp2.waitFor()` method, but it isn't good. I think the "start" parameter, after `cmd.exe /C start` in new process, what I can't control.
If anybody has some advice, please give me. Thank's.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `StreamGobbler` (see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609762/need-sample-java-code-to-run-a-shellscript/609783#609783) or this [simple one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755557/how-can-i-unblock-from-a-java-started-process/755738#755738)) to look for the completion of your command before going on with the rest of your program.

Note: read both standard out and standard error [is advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865277/executing-shell-scripts-from-a-java-application-independently).

Notebis: as this [SO answer illustrates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755557/how-can-i-unblock-from-a-java-started-process/755840#755840), running a 'cmd' without the start might enable the `.waitFor()` to do what you want.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd + " < c:\\someTextFile.txt", null, cmdDir);
...
int errCode = p.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running java without using start:

```
String run_tool ="cmd.exe /C java ...
```