# how to integrate Bash with Java

Tags: java, linux, bash

Can any body help me with how to compile a bash script as part of a java program. I am writing a simple java program that i want to use to invoke bash script commands.

---

my java code looks like the following:

```
    try{
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("myscript.sh"); 
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())); 

        String line = null;  

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){  
                    System.out.println(line); 
        }  
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

and the "mysrcipt.sh" file is a simple script that contains the following lines

---

## !/bin/bash

echo "enter your input followed by [ENTER]:"

read -e choice

echo $choice

---

My problem is, the program waits for an input at the read command in the script even if i enter multiple lines and press enter several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to see some code showing what you're trying to accomplish.

Executing bash script in Java can be done using something like the following...

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec("YOUR COMMAND STRING");

List<String> lines = IOUtils.readLines(process.getInputStream());
```

Comment: That's `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils`, incidentally, not the standard Java libs.

Comment: Good point, I snatched that out of a piece of code I wrote a while ago and didn't check the imports. I +1'd Reimeus' answer for its more general form.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash_script.sh"); 
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));  
String line = null;  
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
   // use bash script line output
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Runtime.exec() is what you need to execute your bash script, but be aware there are a few pitfalls.  I found [this](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4) to be a good article when starting to call external scripts.

It is written for a windows platform, but a lot of what is discussed is relevant to *nix as well.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609762/need-sample-java-code-to-run-a-shellscript).

Comment: About the article, did you take a date that the article was posted? Dec 29, 2000 12:00 AM?